# (ASM) Fibonacci Function using fewer registers?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am following a beginner's guide to MIPS ASM.

The question is:

> Write the program as a counting loop that terminates when the first
>   100 terms of the Fibonacci series have been computed.  **Use a register
>   for the current term and a register for the previous term. Each
>   execution of the loop computes a new current term and then copies the
>   old current term to the previous term register.**

It seems as though the solution should only use 2 registers; previous and current value. And another 2 for counter and '101' (the book says to use 101 in a register for the beq instruction)

**Is it possible for me to remove the 'sum' register from my solution?** 
I'm a beginner programmer and this is blowing my mind.

It's wrong because it does not computer 1,1,3,5,8...
Instead it computes 1,3,5,8. I don't know how to computer '1' twice by following the book's method.

My solution, based on the question:

```
## fibonacci series ##
# $7=sum    $8=prev     $9=current  $10=counter     $11=101 #
.text
main:

ori $7,$0,0     # init sum 0
ori $8,$0,0     # init prev 0
ori $9,$0,1     # init current 1
ori $10,$0,0        # init counter 0
ori $11,$0,101  # init 101

loop:
beq $10,$11,exit
addu $7,$8,$9       # sum = prev+current
or $8,$0,$9         # copy old current to prev
or $9,$0,$7         # copy sum to new current
addiu $10,$10,1    # counter+1
j loop               # go to loop
sll $0,$0,0

exit:
j exit
sll $0,$0,0        # exit
```

Comment: Michael has already given a good answer, just wanted to point out that you only need one register for the counter also, If you start at 100 instead, decrement once for each loop and use bltz, so then you are down to a total of 3 registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
addu $9,$9,$8    # current += prev
sub  $8,$9,$8    # prev = current - prev  (== old current)
```